# Ansible structed output, get only one specific output

Tags: ansible

I have this output:

`ospf_struct:
  - Neighbor: 1.1.1.2
    Neighbor_is_up: 1w2d
    interface_address: 1.1.1.2
    via_interface: GigabitEthernet0/1`

Could you help me to create a variable that stores only "via_inteface: GigabitEthernet0/1"

My playbook, is look like this:

```
---

- name: "REPORT -"
  hosts: ios
  connection: network_cli
  become: yes
  become_method: enable
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   OSPF_command: show ip ospf nei det

  tasks:

    - name: "Run command"
      ios_command:
        commands: "{{ OSPF_command }}"
      register: ospf

    - name: "Run Template"
      set_fact:
        ospf_struct: "{{ ospf.stdout[0] | parse_cli_textfsm('/etc/ansible/playbooks/test.template') }}"

    - name: Display outuput
      debug:
         var: ospf_struct

    #- name Print only one-variable with the value "GigabitEthernet0/1"
       #How could i get this happen.
```

Thanks!

/Mohammed

I tried to make a nice json "ospf_struct: `"{{ ospf.stdout[0] | parse_cli_textfsm('/etc/ansible/playbooks/test.template') | to_nice_json }}"`

and tried to debug out but it does not work either

```
debug:
   var: ospf_struct.via_interface
```

Comment: It should be `ospf_struct.0.via_interface`. `ospf_struct` is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: I get this error: ```ospf_struct.0.via_interface: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!```

Comment: What's the output of `debug: var: ospf_struct`?

Comment: `
    ospf_struct:
  - Neighbor: 1.1.1.2
    Neighbor_is_up: 1w2d
    interface_address: 1.1.1.2
    via_interface: GigabitEthernet0/1  
`

See the orginal post!
Thanks.

Comment: Just making sure, `debug: var: ospf_struct.0` and `debug: var: ospf_struct.0.via_interface` are undefined?

Comment: I got same error before: `ospf_struct.0.via_interface: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!`

Comment: Now, it worked with msg instead off var:

`debug:
         msg: "{{ ospf_struct.0.via_interface }}"`

Thanks #Alassane for your support

Answer (score 0):

Now, it worked with msg instead off `var: debug: msg: "{{ ospf_struct.0.via_interface }}"` Thanks #Alassane for your support –